# How to adjust player sprite speed correctly? (Basically a math question?)

Tags: math, vector, angle

Background: I have a bird view's JavaScript game where the player controls a space ship by touching a circle -- e.g. touch to the left of the circle center, and the ship will move left, touch the top right and it will move to the top right and so on... the further away from the circle center of pseudo joystick, the more speed in that direction. However, I'm not directly adjusting the ship's speed, but rather set a targetSpeed.x and targetSpeed.y value, and the ship will then adjust its speed using something like:

```
if (this.speed.x < this.targetSpeed.x) {
    this.speed.x += this.speedStep;
}
else if (this.speed.x > this.targetSpeed.x) {
    this.speed.x -= this.speedStep;
}
```

... and the same for the y speed, and speedStep is a small value to make it smoother and not too abrupt (a ship shouldn't go from a fast leftwards direction to an immediate fast rightwards direction).

My question: Using above code, I believe however that the speed will be adjusted quicker in diagonal directions, and slower along the horizontal/ vertical lines. How do I correct this to have an equal target speed following?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Could you rephrase just your question please? What exactly is it that you want to do? Thanks.

Comment: @Oren: It's pretty obvious what the OP wants to do---make it so that if, say, the angle is 45 degrees (e.g., `targetSpeed.x - speed.x == targetSpeed.y - speed.y`), then the increment is still `speedStep`, not `sqrt(2) * speedStep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var xdiff = targetSpeed.x - speed.x;
var ydiff = targetSpeed.y - speed.y;
var angle = Math.atan2(ydiff, xdiff);
speed.x += speedStep * Math.cos(angle);
speed.y += speedStep * Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it. atan2 will get the angle between 2 points. cos and sin get your x and y offsets. I would have just used speed step instead of calculating norm on the last 2 lines though.

Comment: Works like a charm, I love Stackoverflow! Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already checked that the touch is inside the circle, and that the edge of the circle represents max speed, and that the center of the circle is `circleTouch == [0, 0]`

In some C++-like pseudo code:

```
Scalar circleRadius = ...;
Scalar maxSpeed = ...;
Scalar acceleration = ...;

Vector calculateTargetSpeed( Vector circleTouch ) {
    Vector targetSpeed = maxSpeed * circleTouch / circleRadius;

    return targetSpeed;
}

Vector calculateNewSpeed( Vector currentSpeed, Vector targetSpeed ) {
    Vector speedDiff = targetSpeed - currentSpeed;

    Vector newSpeed = currentSpeed + acceleration * normalized(speedDiff);

    return newSpeed;
}

// Divide v by its length to get normalized vector (length 1) with same x/y ratio
Vector normalized( Vector v ) {
    return v / length(v);
}

// Pythagoras for the length of v
Scalar length( Vector v ) {
    Scalar length = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y); // or preferably hypot(v.x, v.y)

    return length;
}
```

This is just off the top of my head, and i haven't tested it. The other answer is fine, i just wanted to give an answer without trigonometry functions. :)

Comment: Great to have this as alternative, thanks Christoffer! Do you suspect this code may be a faster alternative because it avoids certain math functions?

Comment: @Philipp: Sorry, i have no idea, you'd have to benchmark for yourself. Also, i hope the vector math was understandable enough? :)